# Error in collections-deque - Python

Tags: python, deque

I am trying to have a queue using deque in python.

The error I keep getting is index out of range

```
perf_his[b][c] = 0
```

IndexError: deque index out of range

Here is a small prototype of the code that I implemented.

```
import collections

apps = [1,2,3]
num_thrs = len(apps)
perf_his = []
for a in range(num_thrs):
 perf_his += [collections.deque(maxlen=1)]

for b in range(num_thrs):
 for c in range(0, 1):
  perf_his[b][c] = 0
```

Inorder to check if I did understand deque correctly, I implemented this code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from collections import deque

something = ["foo","bar","baz"]
output = []
diff = 0

d = deque()

for i in something:
    d.append(i)
    print("-> %s" % i)

for i in xrange(len(d)):
    print(d[i])
    output.append(d[i])

for i in xrange(len(something)):
    if output[i] != something[i]:
        diff += 1

print(something,output,diff)
```

I've been trying to fix the error in like 2 days, I don't seem to understand the problem.
can someone please shed some light?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4020264/check-maxlen-of-deque-in-python-2-6

I took help of this code. .when I was implementing the prototype.

Comment: If maxlen is 1, it would seem obvious indexes of more than 0 won't work.

Comment: @lattyware: That was just an example. I had `maxlen` of 5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first bit of code, you never `append()` to the `deque`, and thus it never *has* an element "0", and thus you aren't allowed to assign to it. Setting `maxlen` doesn't create elements, it just limits how many elements can be present later on.

What you probably want instead is this:

```
for a in range(num_thrs):
  perf_his += [collections.deque()]

for b in range(num_thrs):
  for c in range(0, 1):
    perf_his[b].append(0)
```

Comment: Thanks. So, this will have a deque something like this right?
assuming the range of thrs is 3
`[[0],[0],[0]]`
am I correct?

Answer (score 1):

When *maxlen* is set, the deque still is size zero until elements are added.  The effect of *maxlen=5* is that after five appends, then next append will automatically pop the oldest element so that the size never get bigger.   In other words, *maxlen* is the maximum size, not the minimum.

For your application, the deque needs to be prepopulated with initial values before you can make any assignments:

```
>>> d = deque([0] * 5, maxlen=5)
>>> d[2] = 100
>>> d
deque([0, 0, 100, 0, 0], maxlen=5)
```

Comment: One other thought -- deques aren't usually the right data structure if you're going to make indexed assignments such as ``d[i] = x``.  Deques are primarily designed for appends and pops at the endpoints.